# Using 'not in' and 'or' in a while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I'm trying to use a while loop to make sure an input is one I want. This bit of code is an example of what I'm trying to do. Is there any way to make this work?

Thank you.

```
colours=["red","black","blue"]

colour=raw_input("enter a colour")
while colour not in colours or colour!="exit":
    colour=raw_input("enter a colour")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `and` instead of `or`:

```
while colour not in colours and colour!="exit":
```

Your current code will loop continually because `colour` will *always* be either not in `colours` or not equal to `"exit"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
while colour not in colours and not colour == "exit":
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
color_list = ["red", "black", "blue"]
while True:
    color = str(raw_input("Enter a color: ")).strip()
    if (color.lower() in color_list or color.lower() == 'exit'):
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

Writing it this way avoids the duplication of the prompt. The termination condition also reads more naturally.

```
while True:
    colour = raw_input("enter a colour")
    if colour in colours or colour == "exit":
        break
```